Evaluate the line integral of $\textbf{F}(x,y,z) = (f(x),g(y),h(z))$ along the curve $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1$
Consider the vector field $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=f(x) \vec{i} + g(y) \vec{j}+ h(z) \vec{k}$ where $f,g,h$ are continuous functions. Evaluate
$$
\int_{\mathcal{C}}\vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr},
$$
where $\mathcal{C}$ is the curve $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=1.$
Now, to solve such line integrals, I have started by writing the parametrization of $\mathcal{C}$ as
$$
\vec{r}(t)=(\cos t)^3 \vec{i}+(\sin t)^3 \vec{j}+0\vec{k},\ \ \ t\in[0,2\pi],
$$
then I compute
$$
\dfrac{\,d\vec{r}}{dt}=-3\sin(t) \cos^2(t) \vec{i}+3\cos(t)\sin^2(t) \vec{j}.
$$
Now to be able to evaluate the line integral, how one may write
$$
\vec{F} \cdot \dfrac{\,d\vec{r}}{dt},
$$
and then to be able to evaluate the line integral?

Based on the proposed conditions, it results that
\begin{align*}
\langle\textbf{F}(\textbf{r}(t)),\textbf{r}'(t)\rangle & = -3\sin(t)\cos^{2}(t)f(\cos^{3}(t)) + 3\sin^{2}(t)\cos(t)g(\sin^{3}(t))
\end{align*}
But we do not need to consider its explicit expression.
Since $\nabla\times\textbf{F} = 0$ and the components of $\textbf{F}$ are continuous, one can conclude the proposed integral is equal to $0$ due to the fact that $\mathcal{C}$ is a closed curve.
Hopefully this helps!

Yes am sure there is no additional information, and that is why I got stuck when solving it.

@Student I have edited my answer.
